# How can I trigger an ant task only if input is newer than output?

Tags: ant

I have a build process in Java where I need to use the Ant `exec` task to launch an external program. That external program will then create some sources based on an abstract specification, i.e. a kind of code generation.

How can I get the `exec` task to execute only if the *input* to the code generation is newer than the *output*? I.e. when the input has been modified after the output was last created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I wanted to specify an arbitrary set of target files (which is cumbersome or impossible with `Uptodate` that only uses the Ant `mapper` element for multiple target files), I ended up using the `ant-contrib` [OutOfDate](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/outofdate.html) task which supported what I wanted more intuitively.

Comment: Very cool.  I had not seen that one in ant-contrib yet.  I'll have to try it next time I have a similar problem.  That sounds like one of the features that would be handy but not necessarily fighting against Ant.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Uptodate](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html) task to set a property and add an `if` or `unless` with that property to the target which contains your `exec` task.

Comment: this is the good advice.  However don't use the ant-contrib if, go with unless on the target as @barnesjd ponits out.  If you're on 1.9 you can use the native if  http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html

Comment: +1 on the ant-contrib comment from @thekbb. It can be handy.  However, any time I use it, I feel I'm getting away from the spirit/philosophy of Ant (like it or not) and I find myself fighting Ant rather than working with it.