# compile *.clj sources only if modified (with `clojure.core.Compile`)

Tags: clojure

I am using the method proposed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14963239/274677) to compile Clojure `*.clj` files to `*.class` (and subsequently jar them), using more or less the structure of the `compile-clojure` target from the `build.xml` file that's found at the root of the Clojure distribution (e.g. in `clojure-1.5.1.zip`). In my case:

```
<java classname="clojure.lang.Compile" 
      failonerror="true"
      fork="true">
  <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
  <sysproperty key="clojure.compile.path" value="${cljbuild.dir}"/>
  <arg value="${project.MainClass.name}"/>
</java>
```

The problem with this approach is that it keeps compiling the `*.clj` files even though they haven't changed. Any ways around this?

Comment: Is this a mixed Java/Clojure/Something-else project? Is there a strong reason not to use Leiningen?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt: It's a mixed Java/Clojure project (ultimately trying to package some Clojure code as an Ant task to be used by my build process). Prefer not to use Leiningen, yet, before I understand a bit of the magic it "hides".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ant-contrib's [OutOfDate](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/outofdate.html) task (e.g. as also described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18990135/274677) for the more general case of invoking Ant's `exec` task).

```
<contrib:outofdate>
    <deletetargets all="true"/>
    <sourcefiles>
        <path refid="compile.dependency.artifacts"/>
    </sourcefiles>
    <targetfiles>
        <fileset dir="${cljbuild.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.class"/>
        </fileset>
    </targetfiles> 
    <sequential>
        <java classname="clojure.lang.Compile" 
              failonerror="true"
              fork="true">
          <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
          <sysproperty key="clojure.compile.path" value="${cljbuild.dir}"/>
          <arg value="${project.MainClass.name}"/>
        </java>
    </sequential>
</contrib:outofdate>
```

Answer (score 0):

For building Clojure projects where for various reasons I could not use Leiningen I have been much happier using the [Zi plugin](http://palletops.com/zi-the-maven-plugin-in-clojure/) and letting maven decide what needs to be re-compiled.